# Iterate over an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration

I have array with multiple IDs as below. I want to loop over to get individual values. I was thinking of something like this.

```
def letter(billing_ids)
 @billings = Billing.find(billings_ids.split(","))
 @billings.each do |bill|
  puts "#{bill}" 
 end
end
```

but I am getting an error **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Billings with 'id': ([66,  68]) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2)**

**ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Invoice with 'id'=[47]**

I am getting the below array from this query -

```
Office.all.each do |office|
  billing_ids=[] #initialize array
  office.issues.where("issues.amount > 0").each do |issue|
    billing_ids << issue.billings.where("billings.date < ?", Message.last.date).order(:date).last.id
  end
  puts (billing_ids)
end

[66, 68]
[47]
```

Please help me figure out how can I do this.

update

```
def letter(billing_ids)
 @billings = Billing.where(id: billings_ids.split(","))
 @billings.each do |bill|
  puts "#{bill}" 
 end
end
```

Update 2:

```
def letter(billing_ids)
 puts "#{billing_ids}"
end
```

output in terminal

```
 [66, 68]
 [47]
```

Update 3

used byebug to figure out what is going wrong and this is what I could find when I do

```
@billings = Billing.where(id: billing_ids) 
@billings.each do |bill| 
 byebug 
 puts bill.id
end
```

MethodError Exception: undefined method `each' for "[66, 68]":String

Comment: `find` will explode with an exception if it can't find a given record. For a softer approach: `where(id: billing_ids.split(','))`

Comment: If you're taking the output of the second chunk of code then that should be an array already, the `split(',')` part makes no sense.

Comment: @tadman please check the update in the question. How can I access the id from the loop?

Comment: If you've loaded a `Billing` instance then `bill.id` will be the ID of any given `Billing` object.

Comment: @tadman please have look at update 3 in the question

Comment: I'm not sure how you ended up with that mangled array, but my guess is somewhere you did something like `return "#{billing_ids}"` which ends up stringifying them. Don't do that. `"#{x}"` is not necessary, just do `x` or in rare cases `x.to_str` to make it clear what you're doing.

Comment: Could you show us the context of the `letter` method call? Where and how do you call the method? The current question doesn't show what data is supplied to the `letter` method.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split.
 Ruby scope accepts array:

```
 @billings = Billing.where(id: billings_ids)
```

Comment: how can I iterate over billings so as to get the id?

Comment: `def letter(billing_ids)
 @billings = Billing.where(id: billings_ids)
 @billings.each do |bill|
  puts "#{bill.id}" 
 end
end`

it just shows 68. it doesn't print 66 and 47

Comment: if I do puts right after def letter(billing_ids) puts "#{billing_ids}" then it shows [66, 68]
[47]

Comment: where is the part that you called the letter-function?

Comment: Sorry, which part are you asking about?

Comment: I am using the letter function to generate emails based on the IDs

Comment: >"if I do puts right after def letter(billing_ids) puts "#{billing_ids}" then it shows [66, 68] [47] " - can you show this part of code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206118/discussion-between-navroop-and-fernand).

Comment: I used byebug to figure out what is going wrong and this is what I could find when I do `@billings = Billing.where(id: billing_ids)
@billings.each do |bill|
            byebug
            puts bill.id
        end`
MethodError Exception: undefined method `each' for "[66, 68]":String

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse(billing_ids).each{|bill| bill} solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

please try this..it will work

`@billings = Billing.where(id: billing_ids) 
@billings.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).each do |bill| 
 byebug 
 puts bill.id
end`

`.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)` this will convert string in to integer array